# Get WebException on compatible S3 storage

Tags: vb.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I develop an application that connects with a compatible S3 server located in an internal network. For that reason, the server where this app is going to run does not have internet connectivity.

I am using the amazon web service sdk (AWSSDK.S3) to connect with the server and it provides all the necessary functionality.

When I try to connect with the server, it seems that the SDK tries to connect with a real amazon webservice server and it fails.

This is the code I am trying

```
Dim config As AmazonS3Config = New AmazonS3Config With {
    .ForcePathStyle = True,
    .ServiceURL = cloudEndpoint,
    .RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region)
}

config.Validate()
s3Client = New AmazonS3Client(cloudAccessKey, cloudSecretKey, config)
Dim listBuckets As ListBucketsResponse = s3Client.ListBuckets()
```

The S3Client is generated correctly but when I tried to get the buckets, I get the following exception:

```
Error creating s3. Exception: Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: A WebException with status ConnectFailure was thrown. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ** 52.216.143.230:80 **
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpRequest.GetResponse()
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at TestS3.S3CDM..ctor(String endpoint, String accessKey, String secretKey, String region, String bucketName)
   at TestS3.Form1.btn_CreateConnector_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

The server (52.216.143.230:80) that appears in the exception is not my s3 server, searching I find that it´s an amazon server.

Is it necessary connectivity to internet to use this SDK? Or I forget any additional configuration?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need an active Internet connection to connect to anything in AWS.  I have been using [Sprightlysoft's library](https://sprightlysoft.com/AWSComponent/) to connect with AWS.  If you continue to struggle with Amazon's delivered product, you might want to consider it as an alternative.  When you say the IP isn't **my s3 server**, unless you are actually running your own server with a fixed IP, you should assume that the IP address you think you are connecting to may change.  There are many reasons for that like edge cache servers, load balancers etc. and infrastructure may change over time.

Comment: @technonaut Why it´s necessary and active internet connection? I mean, if I have my s3 compatible server which I access locally why it is necessary to contact a real server...I suppose that it's to share statistics with amazon but it's not possible to remove this characteristic

Comment: I might not have read that clearly enough to start with, now I see.  I can't answer your question, but can offer you something that might help: lacking other options, you can always try running Wireshark on your machine to see what's being transmitted.

Comment: You should clarify your question by including the name of the third-party server software you are using to connect to, and tag your question with it (if possible).